# How to save json feed to MongoDB in Laravel and get the key?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I need the following: I make GET requests to the API and receive responses in JSON format. 
We have some sort of logs about responses and I'd like to keep record about the content of these JSON objects on the moment of the request.
In the Laravel command, I have to:

1) Save JSON object to MongoDB and get the unique key "feed_id" from collection under which it was saved.

2) Save the "feed_id" to the table column, where we store logs about history of requests.

How can I implement the first step in Laravel? I have seen some example, but without getting the id.

Answer (score 0):

there is a excellent package for mongoDB in laravel named jenssegers/mongodb
you can install it via composer.
once you've installed it , you can simply insert an object and get the id in response like you do with eloquent and mysql